# Adding dynamic links/buttons to email (sending from web application)

Tags: html, css, email

Anyone managed to make simple button styles that could be used to make buttons similar to the ones below?  I've got an email system that will add dynamic links before sending and I'm struggling to generate the HTML that works across any of the formats I have here.  The two I'm testing with are Hotmail and Outlook 2010.

[image]

This is really my first foray into email css and didn't realise how limited it was in terms of available CSS.

So far I've tried these as the inline styles on the a tag:

```
font-family:Arial; 
background:#025798; 
font-size:16px; 
color:#ffffff; 
text-align: center; 
text-decoration:none; 
margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
```

But I've discovered that margin and padding aren't well supported, width and height were getting stripped out too.  I even tried adding them as a table with the `td` within the `a`, but predictably that didn't work either.

Anyone tried to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the html you would use for your button:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="merchandiseButton">
  <tr> 
     <td align="center" valign="middle" class="merchandiseButtonContent">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="">Purchase</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the inline css style:

```
.merchandiseButton{background-color:#D83826;}
.merchandiseButtonContent, .merchandiseButtonContent a{color:#F0F0F0; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; letter-spacing:-1px; padding:10px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;}
```

Here's a good list to see what css is and isn't supported for each email client:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid margin. Something like this will work for you:

```
<table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="50" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#025798" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 28px;">
<a href="" style="color: #FFFFFE; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Yes</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can use an image, or even better, an image background on a text button. This technique allows the text to remain even with images turned off.

Check out [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/) which uses image backgrounds and VML as a fallback for Outlook (which doesn't support image backgrounds in email page elements).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EH3rJ/) :

```
<table width="320" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#0267BA" align="center" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <tr>
            <td width="300" style="padding-bottom:12px; padding-top:14px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
                <center>
                    <a target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:20px; font-weight: normal; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Regular', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; width:100%; display:inline-block" href=""><span style="color: #ffffff; font-size:20px;text-decoration: none;">I'm A button-like</span></a>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

But the border-radius wont work in all clients.

You may also use this tool to **[test your newsletter in most email clients](https://litmus.com/email-testing)**

## EDIT:

Added span to the link

Here are screenshots for the clients:

## Outlook 2010

[image]

## Hotmail (outlook.com on IE)

[image]